# How to use Jsoup with Volley?

Tags: android, jsoup, android-volley

I have a working example with Jsoup and AsyncTask, and that works fine. I am just not satisfied with the performance. It takes 3-6 seconds to load a simple list page with text and images.

I want to boost the performance somehow... so I have stumbled on volley.

Can anyone explain hot to use volley with jsoup?

I use this to get the doc object that holds the particular URL:

```
 public Document GetDocument(String site) {      
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(site).timeout(600000)
        .data("query", "Java")
        .userAgent("Mozilla")
        .get();

        return doc;
 }
```

I guess I would only analyze the data with jsoup and connect/download with volley? Whene I use Jsoup.connect(site).timeout(600000) I should do that with volley ?

Can anyone write/link a simple example using volley and jsoup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can anyone write/link a simple example using volley and jsoup?

Under the hood, Jsoup make use of `HttpUrlConnection`. This class has known unresolved issues, bugs and performance issues on the Android Platform.

Instead, load the data with Volley first then parse it with Jsoup.

#### Sample Code:

```
private static RequestQueue myRequestQueue = null;

public Document GetDocument(String site) throws Exception {   
   final Document[] doc = new Document[1];
   final CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(1);
 
   StringRequest documentRequest = new StringRequest( //
        Request.Method.GET, //
        site, //
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(String response) {
               doc[0] = Jsoup.parse(response);
               cdl.countDown();
           }
        }, //
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               // Error handling
               System.out.println("Houston we have a problem ... !");
               error.printStackTrace();
           }
        } //
   );

   if (myRequestQueue == null) {
       myRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
   }

   // Add the request to the queue...
   myRequestQueue.add(documentRequest);

   // ... and wait for the document.
   // NOTE: Be aware of user experience here. We don't want to freeze the app...
   cdl.await();

   return doc[0];
}
```

#### References

- [An Introduction to Volley](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-volley--cms-23800)
- [Transmitting Network Data Using Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Comment: It work great. Explanation + example = perfect. This is the correct answer. Thank you. I`l post this answer with little modifications I have made.

Answer (score 1):

With Stephan`s answer I have made some little modifications to this code and it looks like this. I have added UTF 8 support so it can read other languages and specified the retry policy.

```
private static RequestQueue myRequestQueue = null;

public Document GetDocument(String site) {
    final Document[] doc = new Document[1];
    final CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(1);
    try {

        StringRequest documentRequest = new StringRequest( //
                Request.Method.GET, //
                site, //
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        String newStr = null;
                        try {
                            newStr = URLDecoder.decode(URLEncoder.encode(response, "iso8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        doc[0] = Jsoup.parse(newStr);
                        cdl.countDown();
                    }
                }, //
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // Error handling
                        System.out.println("Houston we have a problem ... !");
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } //
        );

        if (myRequestQueue == null) {
            myRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity._Instance);

            documentRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        }

        // Add the request to the queue...
        myRequestQueue.add(documentRequest);

        // ... and wait for the document.
        // NOTA: Be aware of user experience here. We don't want to freeze the app...
        cdl.await();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("TMS", "Error parsing page " + site);
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return doc[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Volley to your project.

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
```

Then use the code below,

```
 runOnUiThread(() -> {
 // Stuff that updates the UI
 new Thread(() -> {
     
     final StringBuilder builder1 = new StringBuilder();
     
     String url = "your.url.com";                                   //RequestQueue initialized
     RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);     //String Request initialized
     StringRequest mStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, response -> {
     
     //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Response :" + response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     
     Document doc = Jsoup.parse(response);
     
     Elements trs = doc.select("table.content tr");
     
     for (Element tr : trs) 
         {
             Elements tds = tr.getElementsByTag("td");
             Element td = tds.get(0);
             builder1.append(td.text()).append(",");
         }
         
         String str1 = builder1.toString();
         
         runOnUiThread(() -> {
             String[] items1 = str1.split(",");
             int i = 1;
             while (i < items1.length) 
             {
                 //
                 i++;
             }
             });
             }, error -> Log.i(TAG,"Error :" + error.toString()));
            mRequestQueue.add(mStringRequest);
     }).start();
});
```