# How to get HTML Page fast with Jsoup?

Tags: android, html, hyperlink, android-asynctask, jsoup

I'm trying to get HTML Page from list of link in my android app to generate Link Preview then need to display these preview in RecycleView. I used this Code to get HTML Page

`Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla").get();`

but these code is running jsut in AsyncTask.

when make for loop for each link in List we create new AsyncTask for each link request. that take too long time to finish it?

what the best way to do this with out take long time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Jsoup with Volley?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35674580/how-to-use-jsoup-with-volley)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using WebView instead, see here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup uses `HttpUrlConnection` for fetching the link. On Android this class is notoriously **slow**. This is why you're experimenting those long response times.

Instead use the Volley library, specially designed to adress this issue.

You can find a full example here: [How to use Jsoup with Volley?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35695852/363573)