# Can't get website using jsoup on Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jsoup

I have a problem with getting website with jsoup on Android.

```
public class Parser
{
    Parser()
    {
        new Parser1().execute();
    }

    class Parser1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        String website1 = "http://google.com";
        Document doc;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
```

This code is not execute doInBackground method.

```
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            try
            {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(website1).get();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

And the rest of code.

```
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values)
        {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            Log.d ("OK",doc.toString());

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled()
        {
            super.onCancelled();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to write code without class AsyncTask, but always on Json.connect the program was exception. 
Thanks for all replies.

Comment: What do you mean "the code is not execute"?

Comment: I debug the code in Android Studio and the method "doInBackground" was not execute, but the method "onPreExecute" was executed.

Comment: did you add     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`  to manifest file ?

Comment: Yes, I added with android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.

Comment: `permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` and `permission.INTERNET` are two different things!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
   try {
       doc = GetDocument(website1);
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

   return null;
}
```

Click the following link to get the [full implementation of `GetDocument`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35695852/363573).

#### References

- [How to use Jsoup with Volley?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35674580/how-to-use-jsoup-with-volley)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a httpURLconnections as an alternative and see if that works.
are you getting anything as the debug output for this code?

```
Log.d ("OK",doc.toString());
```