# retrieve useful info from webpage using JSOUP

Tags: java, html, jsoup

How can i retrieve the Contact us link from any webpage in world wide web from it's "footer" part of the page in JAVA.

E.g. find footer element, or an element with id="footer" or having a footer class?

I had tried retrieving all the links from webpage using JSOUP and then running regex `.*contact.*` in it. But I cannot be 100% sure on that the fetched link from this approach is the contact us page of the website.

**Q2**

Is there any other robust approach or if i could use both footer link and my already completed approach to conclude if a page is certainly a contact us page?

Comment: Try this post, it is about retrieving data from website - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38048480/getting-data-from-website-using-jsoup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I cannot be 100% sure on that the fetched link...

#### SHORT ANSWER

You will NEVER be sure.

#### LONG ANSWER

For a given random HTML page, you want to find the "Contact Us" link. This kind of work is trivial for a human. It represents a big challenge for a computer.

I can see some options in your case:

**Option 1:** Crowd sourcing

- Fetch all the website urls you want the "Contact Us" information
- Send them to a crowd service platform asking real people to find the information for you (Rapidworkers.com, Crowdsource.com, Clickworker.com, Amazon Mechanical Turk, microworkers.com)

Check if the platform offer an API.

```
+ work done by human
+ dynamically adapt to unknown pattern
- cost money
- We suck at repetitive tasks
```

**Option 2:** IA (patten searching)

- Train an IA for extracting the information
- Then through at it your websites

Have a look at [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/%7Eml/weka/) for instance or [Java-ML](http://java-ml.sourceforge.net/).

```
+ Automated task
+ Can perform a repetitive task long time
- May take time to built a robust solution
- Risk of false positive or complete miss
```

**Option 3:** Use Jsoup

- Carefully study the pattern of the websites you target
- Tell Jsoup to find the pattern you have detected

This option is a never ending task. You'll have to always feed Jsoup with new patterns. I suggest you having a monitoring system telling you when website escapes any known pattern.

```
+ Automated task
+ Can perform a repetitive task long time
- Take time for studying, discovering, adding new patterns
- Risk of false positive or complete miss
```

**Option 4:** A mix of the three above options

You can have the three options working on the websites you target.

```
+ Reduce chances of false positive or complete misses
+ More confident final result
- Take time for studying, discovering, adding new patterns
- Cost money
```