# Parse HTML page using key words in java

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup, html-parser

I have nearly 100 companies' websites *contact_us* page links. I have to collect all companies' locations which are there in each *contact_us* page. I am trying to use Jsoup, but if I implement using Jsoup that will be specific to one company. I have to implement a generic implementation.

I am considering the following strategy:

- Where ever we find keywords like office, headquarters, etc. I thought to read that block.

For example, see this link: http://www.directenergysolar.com/company/contact-us/

In this page, I have to collect all the addresses.

Is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: https://jsoup.org/

Comment: @NemanjaT Using jsoup I cann't implement specific implementation

Comment: Perhaps you could strip all HTML tags and then use a regex?

Comment: how about http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Your solutions will be as varied as the pages you receive. I'm not sure how to implement a one-size-fits-all solution.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You are right.So I need to implement generic solution.I need your ideas on this

Comment: however you turn it, to build something truly 'generic' you'll need to edit it at your needs. I don't think you'll run into a library called "contact me website HTML finder" :) Probably a combination of the above frameworks (one of them) and some regexp to "smart detect" the contact me information?

Comment: @NemanjaT No I am not asking for the library.I need some suggestions from you people.

Comment: Also look for microdata like google and facebook. Many companies provide microdata for google search or facebook sharing and it is generally JSON or special markup.  The example you provided don´t have microdata embeded (I could not find in a quick eye balling) but worth try on the others. (reference: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data)

Comment: It looks to me like a lot of if statements.. For instance first try to find a tag with an id of "contact-me" or "contactme" etc. If no results try grabbing an element that contains Contact Us and then grab a text after it if it fits a phone regexp etc. Etc. Etc. I doubt there's a true, simple mathematical "do-it-all" solution.

Comment: @JrBenito google is providing any API for this https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

Answer (score 0):

The goal you're aiming is definitively reachable. Jsoup is just a (small) part of the final solution.

Basically, I can see four options here:

- Crowd sourcing
- Machine learning
- Jsoup
- Mix of the three above approaches

Please see the ["extracting info from random webpage using JSOUP"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38050554/363573) answer for the options details.